# execute 2 methods one by one using handlers

Tags: android

Hi  i want to execute one method  and take some time and then ececute run another method.Is there any possibility for this in handler .Give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance.
I am using the below code  in handlers but it is not working properly.

```
            RefreshHandler extends Handler {


    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
        FirstLevelMaths.this.updateUI();
        FirstLevelMaths.this.updateUI1();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {

        this.removeMessages(0);         
        if(isUpdateUI)
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
```

}

```
 private void updateUI(){
    try
    {
        getimages();
        mRedrawHandler.sleep(5000);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
            System.gc();
            System.runFinalization();
    }
}
```

public void updateUI1() {
    try
    {
        getimages1();
        mRedrawHandler.sleep(5000);

```
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
}
```

}

```
 public void updateUI1() {
try
{
    getimages1();
    mRedrawHandler.sleep(5000);

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
}
```

}

I this getImages() and getimages1() are two methods

Comment: both methods are executed simultaneously .Actually i want it one by one i mean first one number displayed after some time another number displayed .I did not got that output using above code,Please Give me some suggestions.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can set Thread.sleep() between 2 methods.
Or if you want to start on e method after another, you can use join() of Thread.

Comment: In your class :

class Test {
     // Call First method
      Thread.sleep(2000);
     // Call Second method
}